# Change position of a variable in Makefile which is added to the Makefile via qmake

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qmake

I want to link a library to a program in `qmake`, so I will use the following line in the `qmake` file:

```
LIBS+=$${localizer_path}liblocalize.so   #1
```

*(Please note that `localizer_path` has been determined and its value is `some/path`)*

As I am using Ubuntu for development, I must include the library path in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH *(so that the program can find the linked library at runtime)* but I want to put it into the qmake file, so I used this trick:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=\\\$\path_to_localizer  #2
```

Which at the above line `path_to_localizer` content is same as `$${localizer_path}`, but since the line finally will be used in `Makefile` I can't use it directly, So I added a variable to the `Makefile` from the qmake file like the below line:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_VARIABLES = localizer_path  #3
```

Now in the generated `Makefile`, I can see that the below line has added:

```
EXPORT_localizer_path = some/path  #4
```

Now I can use `EXPORT_localizer_path` from qmake like the below:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=\\\$\$(EXPORT_localizer_path)  #2 has changed
```

Everything is fine except that `#4` location appears after `#2` in the Makefile and it's like that I'm using `EXPORT_localizer_path` before initializing it. I want to be concise can we determine the order of the variable which is created by `QMAKE_EXTRA_VARIABLES`?

---

Note 1: If I use an absolute path then everything is fine without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to handle the problem: If we use a global variable as the path to the library, it's not a good idea to set the `rpath` as follows:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=\\\$\CUSTOMPATH
```

Instead, we could use `QMAKE_RPATHDIR`:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $${CUSTOMPATH}
```